# cms.war - No such file or Directory

Tags: hippocms

I try to install a test version of [hippocms](https://www.onehippo.org/trails/demo-tutorials-and-download.html). I stuck in

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 45:21 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-02-16T15:18:32+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/200M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.19:start (cargo-run) on project gogreen: Execution cargo-run of goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.19:start failed: Failed to create deployable with implementation class org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.TomcatWAR for the parameters (container [id = [tomcat8x]], deployable type [war]). InvocationTargetException: Failed to parse Tomcat WAR file in [/courierOS-7.x/p.rader/Downloads/developer-trail-11.0.2-iteration-2/cms/target/cms.war]: Failed to find file [/courierOS-7.x/p.rader/Downloads/developer-trail-11.0.2-iteration-2/cms/target/cms.war]: /courierOS-7.x/p.rader/Downloads/developer-trail-11.0.2-iteration-2/cms/target/cms.war (No such file or directory) -> [Help 1]
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today I repeat `mvn clean install -X` and it worked fine.

For every other guy who came here by search: The `-Pcargo.run` uses tomcat and the built-in `tomcat-users.xml` so the only valid account is `admin` and password `admin` like tomcat does.

Comment: `-X` fixed it for me, as well. I think the problem for me was caused by building first with the community edition and then switching to Hippo Enterprise. `-X` resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a clean install before running cargo?

```
mvn clean install && mvn -Pcargo.run
```

edit:

The more modern way of doing it would be:

```
mvn clean verify
```

and then do your cargo.run.

see also [Build Project](https://www.onehippo.org/trails/getting-started/building-a-project.html)

Comment: I do not like to start. Install only like the Handbook guides me.

Comment: when I try do do a -Pcargo.run without an mvn install firsst I get the same error. When I run mvn install first, I do not.

Comment: did you follow the steps in [https://www.onehippo.org/trails/getting-started/building-a-project.html] because the error you're getting only happens when either a "mvn verify" or "mvn install" did not complete successfully.

Comment: No, I follow the steps in the README. I do not verify I do install as my question said and the README guided me. If the README is wrong its a bug and should be reported no matter what the modern way is. Also I do not build a project.